# Markov chains with continuous time - is $P(2)$ having a given form even possible?

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> Is it possible that
> $$
> \begin{vmatrix}
> 0 & 1 \\
> 1 & 0
> \end{vmatrix} = P(2)
> $$
> for any Markov semigroup $\{P(t), t \geq 0\}$?

---

Recalling what properties must hold for transition matrix $P$:

- $\forall t>0$ every row of matrix must sum to 1 and all entries must be non negative
- $P(0) = I$ and $\lim_{t \to 0^+} P(t) = I$
- $P(s+t) = P(s)P(t)$

Any hints appreciated. I suppose we're looking for some kind of contradiction but I couldn't find any clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us abbreviate

$$
  A :=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}.
$$

**Claim:** A Markov semigroup $(P(t))_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ with $P(2) = A$ does not exist.

Here are three different proofs, so you can choose your favourite one. :-)

**Proof 1 ($A$ has no real square root).**

There is no matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ such that $B^2 = A$; indeed, the equality $B^2 = A$ would imply $-1 = \det(A) = (\det(B))^2 \ge 0$.

**Proof 2 (Perron-Frobenius theory).**

For Markov semigroup $(P(t))_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ it follows from Perron-Frobenius theory that each matrix $P(t)$ has only one eigenvalue on the complex unit circle - namely the number $1$.

However, the matrix $A$ has the eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$.

**Proof 3 (The isometry group with respect to the infinity norm is discrete).**

Endow $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the infinity norm and assume that $(P(t))_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ is a Markov semigroup on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $P(2)$ is a permutation matrix. We show that this implies $P(t) = I$ (:= identity matrix) for all $t \ge 0$:

Each $P(t)$ acts contractively with respect to the infinity norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (via $x \mapsto P(t)x$). But $P(2)$ is an isometry with respect to this norm, which readily implies that each $P(t)$ is an isometry. Hence, each $P(t)$ is a signed permutation matrix (see [this MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/288084/102946)). Since every entry of each $P(t)$ is $\ge 0$, this implies that each $P(t)$ is a permutation matrix.

From $P(t) \to I$ as $t \downarrow 0$ we now conclude that $P(t) = I$ for all sufficiently small times $t$. The semigroup law then implies that $P(t) = I$ for all times $t$.

In particular, the permutation matrix $P(2)$ must be equal to $I$, too.

**Remark.** Proofs 2 and 3 are, admittedly, quite an overkill if you are merely interested in the concrete example from the question. But on the other hand, proofs 2 and 3 give us more structural insight and work in more general situations than proof 1.